# How to use two different fonts for Chinese and English in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts, chinese

I want to use Wenquanyi for Chinese and Palatino for English in Firefox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have installed the required fonts properly. You can install fonts by following steps:

1. Open Home folder,
2. Select View->Show Hidden Files
3. Create a new folder and name it as **.fonts**
4. Open **.fonts** folder and copy font files here

Now selecting fonts in Firefox:

1. Open **Firefox**->**Edit**->**Preferences**->**Content** (tab),
2. Under **Fonts & Colors** click **Advanced**,
3. In **Fonts for** list-box select **Chinese** language,
4. Select **Wenquanyi** font in **Serif**, **Sans-Serif** and **Monospace** list-boxes,
5. Now repeat step 3, this time select **Western** for English,
6. Then repeat step 4 with **Palatino** font for English.

You can also uncheck **Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above** check-box.

Also try by changing **Character Encoding**, unless **Western (ISO-8859-1)** (which is default) or **Unicode (UTF-8)** does work.

Comment: On my system , Setting in Western for English does not work. Settings in Chinese language controls this . Thanks

Comment: Does this matter with locale ? Now my locale is zh_CN.UTF-8 .

Comment: Method Krishnan said works only on some sites . Thanks

Comment: @waterloo2005 well, it worked out in some sites. have you tried by unchecking **Allow pages to choose...** ? And I have find out one more thing. Open **Preferences**-> **Content** (tab), under **Languages** click **Choose**. Here add more languages in which you want to display web pages.

Comment: I have unchecked 'Allow pages to choose... '. In language setting , I choose 'zh-cn,zh,en-us,en' . In askubuntu site , it display English using chinese font setting . In wikipedia ,it display English using beautiful Palatino font . Of course , I want to display English using Palatino.